# Assign a datatable value to a variable

Tags: c#, dataset

I am trying to pass a variable from a data source in visual C# to a variable but the code is not returning any values.
The code that I am using to pull the value is:

```
object o = rateTableDBDataSet1.Tables["RateTable"].Rows[1][0];
```

I get a return that there is no row at position 1. Any Ideas?

Comment: Where is the data set getting its data? What does the data in the table look like?

You are trying to index into the second row of the table, and there is no second row in the table according to the error message.

Comment: the data set was is built from an Access database built with the "add new data source" in visual studios. The table has 23 rows and 4 columns

Comment: Try setting a break point, debugging, and hovering over the rateTableDBDataSet1 variable. Click the magnifying glass to look at what's actually in the table and make sure it has your data.

Comment: I just tried that and the data table is empty. Is there a specific was to call a data table? I added the data table using the toolbox in the form edit

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "Call a data table."

Comment: I have DataSet rateTableDBDataSet1 = new DataSet();                      I guess I am having problems getting the actual data into that dataset

Comment: the data set is a in-memory cache of data

Comment: 'new DataSet()' creates a new, empty data set. I'm not quite sure what you need to do to populate it with data from your access database. I would assume that the "add new data source" option would generate some code for you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little bit confused regarding what you want;

if you want to copy structure and data of the datatable to one side to another try the Copy method:

```
    System.Data.DataTable tb = new System.Data.DataTable();
    System.Data.DataTable tb2 = new System.Data.DataTable();
    object obj = new object();

    obj = tb.Copy();//adding to obj if you want....
    tb2 = tb.Copy();// of to another table without carrying the reference
```

Edit:

As per your comment this is an example of what you want:

```
        DataSet rateTableDBDataSet1 = new DataSet();
        //ds = whatever your data is comming from

        bool doesItHaveData = rateTableDBDataSet1.Tables["RateTable"].Rows.Count > 0;

        if (doesItHaveData)
        {
            object col1row1 = rateTableDBDataSet1.Tables["RateTable"].Rows[0][0];
            object col2row1 = rateTableDBDataSet1.Tables["RateTable"].Rows[0][1];

            object col1row2 = rateTableDBDataSet1.Tables["RateTable"].Rows[1][0];
        }
```

your current error probably because there is no data of not 2 records of data(you are accessing the row 1 and the index starts with 0)

Comment: I am new to C# so sorry if what I am asking is confusing. I want to assign a value from a specific cell in a data table to a variable. Right now my program is using constants for rates and I would like to use a data table so I can edit those rates within the program so I don't have to edit the code every time a rate changes. Is that a little more clear?

Comment: good sample clarification on object naming reference to show that working datatables and datacolumns is ZERO-Based index of first actual record is referenced as [0] and not [1].

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to figure out why there is not a second row in 'RateTable.'

In general, your code to get the column values is correct. It's usually better, however, to access the columns by name. This is more readable and is less prone to errors if the order of the columns ever changes:

```
object o = rateTableDBDataSet1.Tables["RateTable"].Rows[0]["Column"]
```

Where "Column" is your actual column name.

Answer (score 0):

```
      public static decimal opcomm { get; set; }
      public static decimal opcommPercentage { get; set; }


      public static void SetOpCommission()
      {
          using (DataBaseClass dataclass = new DataBaseClass())
          {

              dataclass.Connect();

              string sql = @"SELECT  EmployeeComission, EmployeeComissionPercentage,MobileKindId,Id,StartDate FROM EmployeeCommission";

              opcomm = (decimal)dataclass.ExecuteScalar(sql);
              opcommPercentage = (decimal)dataclass.ExecuteScalar(sql);
          }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

It says that your datatable named `RateTable` doesn't contain any row with rowposition 1.

Actually how it represents is

```
object o=dataset.tables[0].[rownumber][columnnumber/"columnname"];
```